# How to use lame.exe in my application?

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, pixelsense, lame

I capture audio files in the wave format in my Microsoft Surface application. Now for file size reasons, I'd like to convert the wave file into a mp3 file. I read in the Internet that a good possibility to do that is using [lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/index.php).

But how can I call this exe file from my application? and how can I include it into my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class to call an external application:

```
string lameEXE = @"C:\path_of_lame\lame.exe";
string lameArgs = "-V2";

string wavFile = @"C:\my_wavs\input.wav";
string mp3File = @"C:\my_mp3s\output.mp3";

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
process.StartInfo.FileName = lameEXE;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(
    "{0} {1} {2}",
    lameArgs,
    wavFile,
    mp3File);

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
```

Comment: Thanks, now I just wonder how to get the exe file? Do I have to compile the source code from the lame project?

Comment: i only know german sites where you can download windows binaries. try to search for "lame windows" in google to find a ready-to-use binary.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try it. (Btw... my german is far better than my english)

Answer (score 2):

```
public void mciConvertWavMP3(string fileName, bool waitFlag)
{
    //maxLen is in ms (1000 = 1 second)
    string outfile= "-b 32 --resample 22.05 -m m \"" + pworkingDir+fileName + "\" \"" + pworkingDir + fileName.Replace(".wav",".mp3") + "\"";
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = "\"" + pworkingDir + "lame.exe" + "\"";
    psi.Arguments = outfile;
    //psi.WorkingDirectory = pworkingDir;
    psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);

    if (waitFlag)
    {
        p.WaitForExit();
        // wait for exit of called application
    }
}
```

Above code [taken from here](http://vinothnat.blogspot.com/2007/11/convert-wav-to-mp3-using-lameexe-in-c.html) .

Depending on the usage, you can incorporate a [`Process.StartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx) object, control properties such as `ShellExecute` and also redirect any output from the application to (say) a log file or UI component.

To bundle the exe with your project, [check this question from stackoverflow out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238744). Personally, I'd go with the first suggestions:

> There are several ways you could
>   accomplish this. First, you should add
>   program.exe to the project. You would
>   do this by right-clicking the project
>   in Visual Studio, and selecting Add >
>   Existing Item... Select program.exe,
>   and it will appear in the project.
>   Viewing its properties, you can set
>   "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy
>   Always", and it will appear in your
>   output directory beside your
>   application.

If you stick to the above method, then reference lame.exe relatively ('....\Tools\Lame.exe' for example).

Finally, according to the official lame site : [RareWares offers several compiled LAME versions, including modified versions featuring special functionality.](http://www.rarewares.org/mp3-lame-bundle.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps! Now the problem is, how can I get the lame.exe and how do I add it to my project so that I can also use it when the application is relaesed``

Comment: I'd need to check for 100% certainty, but I'm sure you could just add the exe to some folder of the project, and reference it relatively (i.e ...\...\Tools\Lame.exe) in the filename property.

Answer (score 2):

You can call an executable from .NET by using the System.Diagnostics.Process class and related classes - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28VS.71%29.aspx) for the documentation.

Lame has pretty robust command line arguments, which can be found [here](http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/USAGE). You can pass command line arguments to the Process using the [ProcessStartInfo.Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks, now I just wonder how to get the exe file? Do I have to compile the source code from the lame project?

Comment: I'd grab the latest executable and include it with the project personally.

Answer (score 1):

There is a DLL version of LAME, I would be surprised if you can't find a VB or C# example using it. Check this discussion thread: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31294459/-lameencdll-and-vbnet.aspx